# Mono GUI Window can not be refreshed after moving from one window to another window

Tags: c, linux, mono

I have ubuntu 12.04 and mono 2.10.8.1 in my Linux PC.

I have one .NET application which continuously capturing image from camera connected in my development board.

It is working fine without any issue if i don't move my GUI windows which is continuously capturing image. But when i moves the tab to another window and get back to mono GUI window at that time GUI can not be refreshed and doesn't display live image from camera.

Also, I have also put one panel in which some data like frames and seconds are also going to displayed fine when application is running properly without moving tab to another window. But when i moved the tab into another window at that time same issue caused here that frames are also not going to refreshed in to that panel.

SO, does any one have idea about what is happening in this condition?

Is there any limitation about mono to refresh GUI window or something else?

Please let me know if any one have update as soon as possible.

Comment: I got the error something like this sometime on my command prompt after running .NET binary using mono.                                                                 ** (mono:3805): WARNING **: Could not connect: Connection refused

Comment: Is any one have idea that this cause any problem on GUI?

Comment: Please help me to solve this GUI refresh issue because i have  already tried with all the mono related optimization option but still mono fails to refresh the GUI sometime. I don't have idea about what is going on with mono. Lets discuss this issue as soon as possible because my project holds due to this issue.